# Dreamweaver Code Hints from Dynamically Included js File?

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver, code-hinting

I am using Dreamweaver CS6 (and most recently, CC).

We have a javascript file that is included in every page, but its dynamically included through nested layers of PHP includes, so when I type in a function name, DW does not know it is part of the page, and therefore does not give me the code hints (vs if I am actually in that js file, code hinting works like a charm).

I am looking for a way to have DW pick up that file and/or give me code hints for any functions and namespaces I place in there, but so far, have come up empty.

Has anyone had any success with doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for this answer for far too long, and I think I've found it! It has to do with "site-specific code hinting". Take a look at this link: https://www.inkling.com/read/dreamweaver-cs6-missing-manual-david-sawyer-mcfarland-1st/chapter-22/php-code-hints

It worked for me. I am now able to see all variables from nested includes.